# POST Request. Exception: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to allow larger files in my .NET Core API, but I am getting this error. A lot of posted fixes to this issue resort to editing web.config. Due to being Core, it does not have a web.config. There is only a web.config when running locally using IIS, so I can get this to work locally.

The issue is that I would like to get this to work in different environments that do not have a web.config.

Here is the web.config code that allows it to function locally.

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

It isn't hitting the code in the controllers. Any help would be appreciated.